# conflict revolution slider and jquery file In wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, conflict

I am using WordPress SLIDER REVOLUTION Plugins. But It is not working and showing my wordpress theme. I Found, It Is conflicting wight "jquery.min.js" File. when I was deleted "jquery.min.js" File In my wordpress theme, Than Revolution slider working. But I add "jquery.min.js" File, Than Revolution slider not showing and working.

Now How can I solved this issue ?

Comment: wordpress has jquery added by default, you don't need another jquery file

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to revolution slider plugin:

[image]

2. Go to global section and 'javascript into footer' is to be on as per highlight section:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated screenshot: Globals > Insert.

[image]